# Is there a way to reverse the letters of cld in multcomp package?

Tags: r

`cld` makes a compact letters display of the differences. The greatest different mean gets an "a" the second a "b" and so on. However I want the least mean to get an "a", ie get the letters in a ascending order insted of a descending order.

Here is a reproducible example from the help:

```
data(warpbreaks)
amod <- aov(breaks ~ tension, data = warpbreaks)
tuk <- glht(amod, linfct = mcp(tension = "Tukey"))
tuk.cld <- cld(tuk)
tuk.cld
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have submitted a contribution to the `multcomp` package. Now the `decreasing` flag control the order of the letters. Setting it to `TRUE` will reverse the order.

```
data(warpbreaks)
amod <- aov(breaks ~ tension, data = warpbreaks)
tuk <- glht(amod, linfct = mcp(tension = "Tukey"))
tuk.cld <- cld(tuk)
tuk.cld
tuk.cld_dec <- cld(tuk, decreasing = TRUE)
tuk.cld_dec
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar w/ the multcomp package, but I noticed that

```
tuk.cld$mcletters$aLetters 
 [1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h" "i" "j" "k" "l" "m" "n" "o" "p" "q" "r" "s" 
[20] "t" "u" "v" "w" "x" "y" "z" "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "F" "G" "H" "I" "J" "K" "L" 
[ 39] "M" "N" "O" "P" "Q" "R" "S" "T" "U" "V" "W" "X" "Y" "Z"
```

Which suggest to me that there's a command switch in `cld()`  that lets you choose whatever set of identifiers you want.   E.g.

```
rev.lets<-rev(c(letters,LETTERS))
```

Comment: Unfortunately the `cld` function is written without a `...` argument to `insert_absorb` which is the function that does the lettering.

Comment: @DWin, Yes, you are right. And even it had `...` that would do the trick since it would just be Z, Y, X, ... a. And I want the letters to be ordered by increasing means. I don't know if that's clear in my question.